# JMS Serializer cannot serialize object to array

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have a class that's only used as a container for an array.

```
class Container {
    private $things = array();

    public function addThing($thing) {
        $this->things[] = $thing;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getThings() {
        return $this->things;
    }
}
```

I would liek to serialize this class using the JMS\Serializer to only the array it contains. To do that, I use a special handler function:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\HandlerCallback;

class Container {
    // ...

    /**
     * @HandlerCallback("json", direction = "serialization")
     */
    public function serializeToJson() {
        return $this->things;
    }
}
```

Now if I run

```
$container = new Container();
$container->addThing('something'); // optional
print_r($serializer->serialize($container, 'json'));
```

my expectation is that I get

```
[
    'something'
]
```

but what I do get is `null`.

I've reported the issue [here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/594), but does anybody know a workaround for this issue? How should I tackle this problem (without using `@HandlerCallback` or some other idea) so that I get the desired outcome?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the visitor object passed as method arguments as follow:

```
/** @HandlerCallback("json", direction = "serialization") */
public function serializeToJson(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor)
{
    $visitor->addData($this->things);
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: As far as I can see, `addData()` takes 2 parameters and adds to an associative array in the `$visitor`. I want to return the `$things` array alone, not encompassed in another array.

Either way, I have tried it and it throws an error looking for the second argument. If I place a key before `$this->things`, the serialization result is still `null`.

Comment: Hi @tetele you are right, the correct signature is `addData($key, $value)` ha ve you tried with something like `$visitor->addData('things', $this->things);`?     otherwise you can also try with `$visitor->setRoot($this->things);`